# I need to find the parameters of Beep(int32,int32); that emits the loudest sound

Tags: c#

I am making a timer in my program and when the timer is up my c# program will use the `Console.Beep(int32, int32);` method to emit a beep from the hardware. But I need help finding which frequency and duration combinations make the loudest beep. If you don't know the parameters mean `Console.Beep(frequency, duration);` the frequency is measured in hertz and ranges from 37-32767 hertz and the duration is measured in milliseconds and has no limit.
Thank for helping.
Here is the link where I got my information from: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is more of a science question: You're looking for the frequency which produces the loudest perceived sound (they're all equally loud in pure decibels). So google for that.

Comment: Frequency and duration should not have to do anything with loudness. You probably cannot change the amplitude of the signal which is responsible for the loudness. But instead you could find a frequency which is most annoying for human perception (eventually there is a maximum in the hearing range). ;)

Comment: Well frequency has, but that depends on the hearing of the humans. Some don't hear low frequencies very well, others have problems with high frequencies. Generally humans with excellent hearing can perceive frequencies from ~20Hz to ~20000Hz. The older you get, the smaller this range becomes.

Comment: http://www.engr.uky.edu/~donohue/audio/fsear.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is "Fletcher–Munson curves". They show the perceived volume of a given frequency to the human ear. 
This is as far as I can say pretty accurate, as I tested it using a synthesizer and an equalizer.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%E2%80%93Munson_curves

I can also say that frequencies around 7000 are at a good range most of the time, the built-in beeper on my Atmega microcontroller did perform quite bad at very low and very high frequencies. That should be applicable to every other built-in beeper.

In the end, best practice should be to sweep trough the whole frequency and check what you perceive as the loudest.

PS: Rotem's link is exactly pointing out what I did.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

They're all played at the same decibel level, so they're all equally "loud".

Comment: Got a source for that? If we're talking a little piezo speaker, it's unlikely to have very uniform frequency response.

Comment: the frequency that is the loudest is 1000 hertz.